# Select by column number SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to select a column by number and change the name of this and the next column. For example: name of column 1 = 'abc', name of column 2 = 'xyz'. After the conversion, name of column 1 = 'abc1', name of column 2 = 'abc2'.

Comment: What determines what column is what number? Do you want to rename columns in the table itself (a huge pain if using a sqlite version earlier than 3.25) or just what columns are named in the results of a select?

Comment: @Shawn I have a column abc and xyz, I need the column abc to be defined as abc1, and xyz to be defined as abc2. abc and xyz follow each other

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions...

Comment: @Shawn I need to select the column that comes after abc, but I do not know its name